# How can I perform the self join in left join table?

Tags: sql

I have two tables

first one is 'blog'  table :

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | title  | status |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | blog 1 |      1 |
|  2 | blog 2 |      1 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Second is blog_activity:

status 1 is: create
status 2 is: opened

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+
| id | blog_id | status |    date    |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 | 2019-09-09 |
|  2 |       2 |      1 | 2019-09-10 |
|  2 |       2 |      2 | 2019-09-11 |
+----+---------+--------+------------+
```

I want the record of the blog not opened with all the detail of the blog table.

Example :

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------------------+
| id | blog_id | title  | blog.date  | blog_activity.date |
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------------------+
|  1 |       1 | blog 1 | 2019-09-09 | 2019-09-09         |
+----+---------+--------+------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses aggregation:

```
SELECT
    ba.id,
    ba.blog_id,
    b.title,
    ba.date
FROM blog b
INNER JOIN blog_activity ba
    ON b.id = ba.blog_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT blog_id
    FROM blog_activity
    GROUP BY blog_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 END) = 0
) t
    ON b.id = t.blog_id;
```

### Demo

The subquery aliased as `t` finds all blogs which do *not* have an opened status associated with them.  In this case, only `blog_id = 1` meets this condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use `exists` and `join`:

```
select b.*, ba.date as created_date
from blog b join
     blog_activity ba
     on ba.blog_id = b.id and ba.status = 1
where not exists (select 1
                  from block_activity ba2
                  where ba2.blog_id = b.id and ba2.status = 2
                 );
```

This avoids aggregation and it can use an index on `blog_activity(blog_id, status)`.